# npm script is unable to locate an existent module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I am trying to execute a ReactJS application on my Windows 10 system using npm.

On running the execution script, it is giving me a compilation error that states:
Module not found: Can't resolve '../assets_new/fonts/lato_bold.woff' in '\src\assets_new\scss'

The file ***lato_bold.woff*** does exist in the given path, yet the script isn't able to locate it.

Can someone pls let me know how could this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this message:

```
Can't resolve '../assets_new/fonts/lato_bold.woff' in '\src\assets_new\scss'
```

It seems that you are trying to fetch `lato_bold.woff` from `fonts` folder in assests_new but you are searching in `scss` folder of assests_new. Try changing it to fonts folder.